# openvz disk used 100%

Tags: debian, partition, openvz

So i discover after a mysql crash that the partion \ is full
I normal condition i got 2 TB

```
root@server:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       39G   32G     0 100% /
none             24G  4.0K   24G   1% /dev
none            4.9G  1.1M  4.8G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
overflow        1.0M  4.0K 1020K   1% /tmp
none             20G     0   20G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

root@server:/# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs     240816105 390981 240425124    1% /
none             6291456     95   6291361    1% /dev
none             6291456     90   6291366    1% /run
none             6291456      3   6291453    1% /run/lock
overflow         6291456      8   6291448    1% /tmp
none             6291456      2   6291454    1% /run/shm
none             6291456      1   6291455    1% /run/user
root@server:/# resize2fs /dev/simfs
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
open: Operation not permitted while opening /dev/simfs
```

I cannot do this command :
umount
resize2fs 
fdisk
......

It's a debian 8 64 bit running in openvz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot handle simfs like common block devices.

If you have enough spare storage on the HN, just assign more to that container:

```
# vzctl set CTID --save --diskspace 100G
```

Comment: i can't access to this command. i re-install every thing

Answer (score -1):

Try searching for what is suddenly using the space ?  Search for all files in root filesystem modified in the last 3 days:

```
find / -xdev -mtime -3 -ls
```

Comment: i already try to delete as mush as possible. the vps got a 2 TB HDD